# 2-column CSS Flex/Grid for UL

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I've spent way too long at work today thinking about this, so I figured I'd ask the internet hive-mind.

I've got a standard `<ul>` with a number of `<li>` elements (currently 12 but could vary). I'd like to arrange these into 2 columns of equal width WHILE also not making the `<ul>` span full block width. The solution also needs to support IE11 unfortunately (no earlier). Any solution needs to also be responsive, so no set non-percentage widths. I've tried a couple different scenarios (you will want to expand snippet to full screen):

**Solution 1 (grid):**

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
li{
   padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>In maximus viverra scelerisque. Vestibulum dignissim ex non</li>
    <li>Sed suscipit, turpis in suscipit consectetur, ante sem.</li>
    <li>Ut et mauris et dui gravida fringilla ut.</li>
    <li>Nullam iaculis fermentum sodales. Proin commodo eleifend lacus.</li>
    <li>Sed molestie, libero at hendrerit sollicitudin, enim nisi.</li>
    <li>Mauris a facilisis dolor. Sed pharetra hendrerit dolor.</li>
    <li>Sed vitae felis tellus. Quisque sagittis, felis vitae.</li>
    <li>Integer et elit metus. Cras congue vestibulum hendrerit.</li>
    <li>Fusce suscipit ante sed tristique euismod. Duis quis.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum quam felis, fringilla in justo malesuada, tristique.</li>
    <li>Integer volutpat quam sed urna iaculis mollis. Maecenas.</li>
    <li>Nullam dignissim ipsum vitae finibus dignissim. Nam viverra.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This above solution essentially works perfectly - it arranges the `<li>`s in 2 columns, the UL is centered in the containing flex div. But of course IE has issues, and while I could use IE prefixes [in the old spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407/), I would still need to manually assign a column/row position for each `li` which is not possible for a list that could potentially have any number of elements.

**Solution 2 (flex):**

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>In maximus viverra scelerisque. Vestibulum dignissim ex non</li>
    <li>Sed suscipit, turpis in suscipit consectetur, ante sem.</li>
    <li>Ut et mauris et dui gravida fringilla ut.</li>
    <li>Nullam iaculis fermentum sodales. Proin commodo eleifend lacus.</li>
    <li>Sed molestie, libero at hendrerit sollicitudin, enim nisi.</li>
    <li>Mauris a facilisis dolor. Sed pharetra hendrerit dolor.</li>
    <li>Sed vitae felis tellus. Quisque sagittis, felis vitae.</li>
    <li>Integer et elit metus. Cras congue vestibulum hendrerit.</li>
    <li>Fusce suscipit ante sed tristique euismod. Duis quis.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum quam felis, fringilla in justo malesuada, tristique.</li>
    <li>Integer volutpat quam sed urna iaculis mollis. Maecenas.</li>
    <li>Nullam dignissim ipsum vitae finibus dignissim. Nam viverra.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

While this above solution is technically acceptable (works well enough, including IE11), the issue here is visual appeal. Because the `<ul>` now spans full width, despite being centered in the containing flex div, the `<li>`s spaning the 50% with left aligned text leaves a large about of visual white space on the right side of each column (wide screen needed to see extra space).

**Solution 3 (tables for IE11):**

I'm not going to bother posting a snippet for this one, as it was the least appealing. Essentially it involved targeting IE11 specifically, setting the `<ul>` to `display:table;`, setting the `<li>`s to `display:table-cell; float: left; width: 50%;` ...long story short, it was a mess that still didn't work visually.

Should I just cut my losses and go with solution 2? I'd really like to get the visual layout of solution 1 if possible... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `display: flex;` property will turn the element into a flex container that affects the layout of the direct child elements only, so if it is only on the outer `div` it is only affecting the layout of the `ul` that is the direct child. For this reason I added `display: flex;` to the `ul` element so the contained child `li` elements get the flexible layout. A great resource for more info on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

In order to address the extra white space I added a max-width to the `ul` less than 100% so the width does not go all the way to the edges, adjust this value as needed. I also changed the padding on the `li` elements, only padding on the left and right, and added `margin-bottom` to space them vertically.

Lastly, I recommend you add a class to your `div` wrapper so you can target everything contextually, otherwise your CSS targeting `div` will hit every `div` in the site, can be very problematic.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 90%; // adjust the width compared to the container
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper li {
  padding: 0 15px; // padding right and left only
  margin-bottom: 20px; // vertical spacing between li elements
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>In maximus viverra scelerisque. Vestibulum dignissim ex non</li>
    <li>Sed suscipit, turpis in suscipit consectetur, ante sem.</li>
    <li>Ut et mauris et dui gravida fringilla ut.</li>
    <li>Nullam iaculis fermentum sodales. Proin commodo eleifend lacus.</li>
    <li>Sed molestie, libero at hendrerit sollicitudin, enim nisi.</li>
    <li>Mauris a facilisis dolor. Sed pharetra hendrerit dolor.</li>
    <li>Sed vitae felis tellus. Quisque sagittis, felis vitae.</li>
    <li>Integer et elit metus. Cras congue vestibulum hendrerit.</li>
    <li>Fusce suscipit ante sed tristique euismod. Duis quis.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum quam felis, fringilla in justo malesuada, tristique.</li>
    <li>Integer volutpat quam sed urna iaculis mollis. Maecenas.</li>
    <li>Nullam dignissim ipsum vitae finibus dignissim. Nam viverra.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't bother adding classes here to simplify things. But unfortunately this solution isn't dynamic enough, as the max-width has to be set explicitly. As I will not know the text-length of each `li`, I need a more self-sufficient solution, like my solution #1 where it centers the `ul` regardless of content. Also, css comments are `/* comment */` :p

Comment: The `ul` is centered no matter what. You want the `li` elements to be 2 across, so width:50%, but 50% of what? unless you want the `ul` to go full width then change the width to 100%. Am I missing something still?

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained it correctly. Try expanding the snippets for my solutions to view the difference in full screen width. You will notice that the ul for solution #1 does not span the full width so it centers in the flex div. This works based on content, without having to set a max-width on the ul. This is the goal, the only problem is it does not work in IE11.

Comment: So you are saying the code works fine, just not in IE?